# Symfony - trying to get all the elements in findBy attribute throws invalid argument supplied for foreach

Tags: php

I have a controller block in my symfony app as shown below where I am using a findBy attribute to get the elements based on the arguments passed to the controller.

This is snippet

```
$alldata = // all data retrieve

$data = array();
foreach ($alldata as $alldata) { //throws invalid arguments supplied in foreach
    array_push($data, $this->serializeData($alldata));
}
```

Please how can I get ride of the warning and retrieve all the elements using the findBy attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
foreach ($alldata as $alldata) {  
    array_push($data, $this->serializeData($alldata));
}
```

to this:

```
foreach ($alldata as $all) {
    array_push($data, $this->serializeData($all));
}
```

The problem is inside the `foreach`, you need to change the second variable with another name

Comment: Perfect! Glad to help you!